# Does it make sense to await a Task when there are no more operations after?

Tags: c#, async-await

Let say that we have a method:

```
public async Task FlushBuffer(List<UmtsCellKpiReceived> kpis)
{
    await _umtsCellService.ProcessUmtsCellKpi(kpis).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Does it make sense to await this `Task` here? In one of the recent discussions I had, I learned that not awaiting creates an orphaned task which risks an `UnobservedTaskException` if `MyTask()` throws.

Is this a valid reason to `await` everything ?

Comment: No as long as you return the task directly. The only reason to use `await` is because you want to do something with the results. If you don't just return the task to the caller.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos is right. I didn't properly read your code.

Comment: @Cemre, please go to this link http://www.albahari.com/threading/part5.aspx#_TaskCreationOptions
and you will see your answer on this topic Exception-Handling Tasks. Hope this helps!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, just a single line method, you can just return the `Task` itself, no async/await required. The calling code is able to await the `Task` itself if it makes sense for it to do so.

Comment: So in that situation, does the method even need to be marked `async`?  I would think not since the purpose of the `async` keyword is essentially to enable the use of the `await` keyword.

Comment: You're correct. You wouldn't mark the method async, and in fact, an async method without any await statements will produce a warning.